# How do I hide or suppress react-native warning

Tags: react-native

I am getting the following warning in my react-native which I am told is something that I can ignore, but the actual warning is annoying.

[image: app screenshot]

The actual text of the error is the following...

> Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `sceneRendererProps.isRequired` was not specified in `SceneView`. Check the render method of `NavigationCard`.

Is there a way I can get rid of, or suppress this error message specifically?

Comment: sceneRenderProps property should be specified. If you have control over the component, and sceneRenderProps is optional, then remove the isRequired from the property definition.

Comment: @Vijay I don't have control over that property and apparently its a bug that hasn't been fixed with navigator.

Comment: You can create IPA or apk by using --dev flag and set it to false , 
example : react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false OR
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false

Comment: @Rajesh I don't want to get rid of all yellow boxes, I want to just suppress this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [This Post](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/5d8ce5daef89616099a53fbcff979813d80d6a96/Example/index.ios.js)

You should be able to do the following...

`console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Warning: Failed propType: SceneView'];`