# Warning: flushSync was called from inside a lifecycle method

Tags: reactjs, mantine, popper

Would anyone know how to debug and fix (or mute) following warning (apparently, [Mantine](https://mantine.dev/) is [dropping](https://github.com/mantinedev/mantine/issues/1823#issuecomment-1190300584) [react-popper](https://popper.js.org/react-popper/) in next major release)?

Everything works fine, but warning is making it very hard to debug other issues.

```
Warning: flushSync was called from inside a lifecycle method. React cannot flush when React is already rendering. Consider moving this call to a scheduler task or micro task.
    at Popper (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mantine/core/esm/components/Popper/Popper.js:67:3)
    at div
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mantine/core/esm/components/Box/Box.js:42:18)
    at Popover (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mantine/core/esm/components/Popover/Popover.js:76:85)
    at O (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js:30:19811)
    at SecretTextareaWithLength (webpack-internal:///./src/main/routes/Create.tsx:106:48)
    at form
    at div
    at O (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js:30:19811)
    at Create (webpack-internal:///./src/main/routes/Create.tsx:291:48)
    at Routes (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-router/index.js:920:5)
    at MenuEvents (webpack-internal:///./src/main/MenuEvents.tsx:34:55)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-router/index.js:854:15)
    at MemoryRouter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-router/index.js:767:5)
    at MantineProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mantine/styles/esm/theme/MantineProvider.js:66:3)
    at App (webpack-internal:///./src/main/App.tsx:40:35)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a [bug](https://github.com/mantinedev/mantine/issues/1823) in mantine  When using Popper. it will be fixed in the next release.

one thing you can do is hack your local react copy to add conditional logic and skip this warning.

another simple  way is  overwriting  the console methods :

```
console.warn =  () => {};
console.warn('warnings skipped.');
```

but in this case all warnings will be ignored

Comment: how about 

const oldConsoleWarn = console.warn.bind(console.warn); 
    
    console.warn = msg => msg === "hello" ? undefined : oldConsoleWarn(msg);
    
    console.warn("not hello") // not hello
    console.warn("hello") // nothing happens

Comment: Yep, that's better. you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64158705/ignore-certain-console-errors-warnings-in-react) it explains it perfectly